# access hidden subreport made visible but shows blank until i go to design view and then back to report view

Tags: ms-access, report, visible, subreport

I have a report that contains a subreport on it. Basically it's a summary report with the details subreport embedded in it. The subreport starts hidden and I have a "Show Details" button on the summary report that opens up/hides the detail report when clicked.

It hides it perfectly but when it opens it up, the subreport shows completely blank. The only way to make it visible is to switch to design view and then back to report view, which I am assuming reruns the report from the query. I have tried to simulate this by calling me.reportname.requery from VBA code but that doesn't work.

Any way I can ensure the subreport opens up win the information on it when I unhide it?

I make the following changes when I hide it:

```
Me.Reportname.visible = false
me.Reportname.height = 0
me.Reportname.width = 0
Me.Detail.height = 1(detail is where the subreport is displayed)
```

When I show it, I do the following:

```
Me.Detail.height = 3
Me.reportname.Visible = True
Me.reportname.height = 1
Me.reportname.width = 20
Me.reportname.requery
```

Comment: Have to ask why? Why does subreport have to be hidden in the first place?

Comment: Because one report shows when it is an employee and another when its a manager.  When it's an employee, it hides the manager one and when its a manager it hides the employee one

Comment: You are hiding/unhiding two subreports? Well, you didn't mention two subreports in your question and your example code does not represent that. I cannot replicate issue. Tested button code and works just fine to hide/unhide subreport container.